# Rails turns options hash into string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, hash, rails-migrations

Alright, this is a really weird problem.  I'm trying to write a library that will extend ActiveRecord::Migrations so that I can write code like this in my Rails migrations:

```
class TestEnterprise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    enterprise_mti_up superclass_table: 'test_superclasses', subclass_tables: ['test_subclass_ones', 'test_subclass_twos']
  end
  def down
    enterprise_mti_down superclass_table: 'test_superclasses', subclass_tables: ['test_subclass_ones', 'test_subclass_twos']
  end
end
```

Here's a sample of the library code:

```
def enterprise_mti_up(*args)
  enterprise_mti args.extract_options!, direction: :up
end

def enterprise_mti_down(*args)
  enterprise_mti args.extract_options!, direction: :down
end
```

When I run the migration in either direction, everything *appears* to work:

```
==  TestEnterprise: migrating =================================================
-- enterprise_mti_up({:superclass_table=>"test_superclasses", :subclass_tables=>["test_subclass_ones", "test_subclass_twos"]})
   -> 0.0005s
==  TestEnterprise: migrated (0.0007s) ========================================
```

But the database remains unchanged because in fact Rails is somehow turning the options hash from enterprise_mti_up and enterprise_mti_down into a string!  When I change one of the functions to manipulate the hash, I get the following results:

```
def enterprise_mti_down(*args)
  opts = args.extract_options!
  puts "opts: #{opts}"
  puts "opts[:superclass_table]: #{opts[:superclass_table]}"
  puts "args: #{args}"
  puts "args.last.class: #{args.last.class}"
  enterprise_mti args.extract_options!, direction: :down
end

...

==  TestEnterprise: reverting =================================================
-- enterprise_mti_down({:superclass_table=>"test_superclasses", :subclass_tables=>["test_subclass_ones", "test_subclass_twos"]})
opts: {}
opts[:superclass_table]:
args: ["{:superclass_table=>\"test_superclasses\", :subclass_tables=>[\"test_subclass_ones\", \"test_subclass_twos\"]}"]
args.last.class: String
   -> 0.0002s
==  TestEnterprise: reverted (0.0005s) ========================================
```

Does anyone have any idea why the hash is being converted to a string and how I can pass a hash to my methods?  Thanks!

**NOTE:** In my testing, I've found that if I pass a string as the first argument before the options hash, everything works the way it's supposed to.  But I shouldn't have to have any arguments before the hash.  This leads me to think that maybe Rails is hard-wired to expect a string/symbol as the first argument in migrations methods.

Comment: Your modified version of `enterprise_mti_down` is broken because it calls `extract_options!` twice, `extract_options!` is a very thin wrapper around `Array#pop`. That said, I'm not seeing the same behavior that you are.

Comment: Try to replace args.extract_options! by args.first

Answer (score 1):

Solved my problem, though I still don't exactly know why it was occurring.  I was using the following line to include my module (ActiveRecord::EnterpriseMtiMigrations) in the ActiveRecord code:

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements.send :include, ActiveRecord::EnterpriseMtiMigrations
```

I had cribbed this line from another gem, acts_as_relation, that adds MTI functionality to Rails.  However, the migration method defined by acts_as_relation takes a string argument and an options hash afterwards.  That pattern matches the way that nearly all the methods in ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::SchemaStatements are defined (e.g., "create_table table_name, opts_hash").

In light of that fact, I had a hunch that by including my methods into SchemaStatements module, I was somehow forcing my first argument to become a string in order to match the pattern described above.  I replaced the line of code above with the following:

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.send :include, ActiveRecord::EnterpriseMtiMigrations
```

And now everything works (after removing the second `extract_options!` as suggested by @muistooshort).  Go figure.

Comment: I'm not sure about this specific case but many things will call `to_s` on their arguments to normalize Strings and Symbols (i.e. to make `m('s')` and `m(:s)` behave the same way). I'd guess that something somewhere deep in the twisted bowels of ActiveRecord was doing that to your SchemaStatements patch. Patching straight into `ActiveRecord::Migration` (or just manually including your module as needed) makes a lot more sense to me. Don't forget that you can accept your own answer in a day.